# Is it possible or recommended to group Laravel commands into nested groups?

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, laravel-artisan

We see Laravel's artisan commands in the typical format of `<module>:<action>`, so there's...

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan cache:clear
// etc.
```

Third party packages add their vendor name in there, so we get...

```
php artisan l5-swagger:generate
```

While that may work for specific packages, what if I want to namespace my application's native commands under the project name as well as the module name? Something along the lines of this:

```
php artisan myapp:auth:create-admin
```

As opposed to simply

```
php artisan myapp:create-admin
// OR
php artisan auth:create-admin
```

Or maybe I want to go crazy and include my vendor name in there too:

```
php artisan myname:myapp:auth:create-admin
```

That's a crazy example, but the simple, one extra level of namespacing will certainly help organizing commands and keeping things looking clean.

Are there any such commands already out there? Is it possible to do this in a manner similar to grouping routes?

I want to avoid creating a "super command" that has sub-commands, something like:

```
php artisan myapp:command Auth CreateAdmin
```

Comment: hello, is opinion base question, so in my opinion, i think all depend on how many Command you plan to have ? if is just couple of, just avoid app namespace.. But if is large app who embed lot of 3th party library who all have command, is better to namespace command and keep it verbose for a better readable.

Comment: @Yanis-git It's not just third-party, but it's my own app which is big in size and will have a lot of commands.

Comment: so yes, if you add to your own, all command who come from 3th party, is better to namespace your command, if i take as example my actual project who are really large i follow this pattern : `app-name:major-section:functionality`. Exemple : `myapp:editor:import-property` or `myapp:media:convert-video`. I hope this can help you.

Comment: @Yanis-git Can you give me a sample command definition?

Comment: will be my pleasure, but i don't get what you really want :( is it more example as i have provided in my previous comment ?

Comment: @Yanis-git No, I meant to ask if you can share the code required to create a command similar to the examples you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following is example of command available on my app :

```
 ps4
  ps4:editor:create                       Create first data ThemeEditor in the database. Options : update | dump
  ps4:editor:export-css                   Export CSS
  ps4:editor:import-css                   Import CSS
  ps4:editor:import-value                 Create first data ThemeEditor in the database
  ps4:export:document                     Routine to generate static file base on release section of backoffice
  ps4:export:html                         Export Accessbility as html files in export.zip file : Requirement : You should put zip file on propal folder.
  ps4:generate                            Full document generation
  ps4:generate:blur:image                 Generate image blur for one document.
  ps4:generate:blur:zoom                  Regenerate all Zoom base64 blur
  ps4:generate:image                      Generate all images of your document
  ps4:generate:onepage                    generate concat of all html in one page
  ps4:generate:uglify                     Uglify generated html/assets to be spyproof
  ps4:generate:vocalization               Generate mp3 by page for a document
  ps4:import:documents                    Massive document Import
  ps4:import:html                         Import Accessbility content from html files
  ps4:import:vocalisation                 Import vocalisation files
  ps4:import:xml                          Import Accessbility content from xml file
  ps4:lunch-worker                        Lunch worker and check if they are alive
  ps4:media:image                         Post traitment media image
  ps4:media:video                         Post traitment media video
  ps4:migrate:accessibility-content       Migrate Accessibility to raw content
  ps4:monitoring:worker                   Command line to monitor our worker
  ps4:optimize:article                    Optimize image on article view.
  ps4:page:generate                       Full document generation
  ps4:page:reset-name                     Reset name of page per number page
  ps4:pdf:html                            Generate html files for specific document and specific pdf.
  ps4:pdf:image                           Convert pdf in images with different size, format, quality.
  ps4:pd:2txt                             Extract from pdf all text splitted by page.
  ps4:worker                              Spawn worker for image traitment
```

And you command can be configure by `$signature` attribute :

```
namespace App\Console\Commands\Editor;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class CreateCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'ps4:editor:create {foo}';
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and it turns out to be ridiculously easy. Thanks!